This method or property cannot be called on Null values
I get this error:

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Infraestructure.Data.AppDbContext'.
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
at lambda_method139(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)   at lambda_method139(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
fail: Infrastructure.Filters.GlobalExceptionFilter[0]
Ha ocurrido la siguiente excepción: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values., con el detalle: , en la hora: 12/10/2024 01:14:23

That problem occurs when running this query:
public async Task<IncidentSolutionResponseDto> GetIncidentSolutionById(decimal incidentId)
{
    // Recuperamos los datos de la base de datos de forma asincrónica
    var data = await _context.IncidentSolutions
            .Where(i => i.ID_Incidente == incidentId)
            .Select(i => new
            {
                i.ID_Incidente,
                i.DuracionIncidente,
                i.LaRespuestaFueEfectiva,
                i.Id_Estado,
                i.RealizoPlanMejoramiento
            })
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 

When does it happen?
When any of the columns in the table are null, if all of them have a value there is no problem. But, if there are some with NULL, it crashes with that error.
This is the DTO:
using System;

namespace Core.DTOs.Incident
{
    public class IncidentSolutionResponseDto
    {
        public decimal Id_Solucion_Incidente { get; set; }
        public decimal ID_Incidente { get; set; }
        public string? DuracionIncidente { get; set; }
        public string? LaRespuestaFueEfectiva { get; set; }
        public string Id_Estado { get; set; }
        public string? RealizoPlanMejoramiento { get; set; }
        public string? LeccionesAprendidas { get; set; }
        public string? ContencionActividades_MitigaciónIncidente { get; set; }
        public string? IncidenteYaSeHabíaPresentado { get; set; }
        public string? Otros { get; set; }
    }
}


Please show us the CREATE TABLE script for the table.

See the linked duplicate. One or more string properties of your entity (not DTO!) is marked as required, while the corresponding column the database table is not and has NULL value. You need to find the offending property and correct the entity model class and/or configuration to reflect the database table column nullability.
